# Specifying position for a command in Ex mode

Tags: vim

I want to remove percentage marks from the following lines:

```
oh_test_() ->
    [
        %{"fold", ?_test(fold(ns()))},
        %{"fold nested", ?_test(fold_nested(ns()))},
        %{"push arg empty table", ?_test(push_arg_empty_table(ns()))},
        %{"push arg table 1", ?_test(push_arg_table1(ns()))},
        %{"push arg nested table", ?_test(push_arg_nested_table(ns()))},
        %{"multicall 0", ?_test(multicall_0(ns()))},
        %{"multicall 1", ?_test(multicall_1(ns()))},
        %{"multicall 2", ?_test(multicall_2(ns()))}
    ].
```

Cursor is on the line with first `%`.

```
:,/%/s/%//
```

Or:

```
:,/%/normal ^x
```

Expected: all percent marks removed. Result: removes only first two percent marks.

1. Why?
2. How should I do it

   - Without using visual mode, and
   - Not counting line numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1:

Your range: `,/%/` is roughly translated starting from the current line. The end of the range will be the next line that matches `/%/` after the current cursor line. This will yield the 2 lines. See `:h :,` for more information.

Question 2:

There are many ways to do accomplish this. You have already presented a `normal` and a `s///` method. One way to fix your commands is to adjust the range. One of the following will work:

- `,/\]\./-1` match the ending `].` and then subtract a line
- `,/^\s*%\(.*\n\s*%\)\@!/` Use a negative look ahead to search for a line that does not start with a `%`.

All together you could use:

```
:,/\]\./-1s/%//
:,/^\s*%\(.*\n\s*%\)\@!/s/%//
:,/\]\./-1norm ^x
:,/^\s*%\(.*\n\s*%\)\@!/norm ^x
```

An alternative to using a macro. The nice thing about using macros in this case is that when an error occurs it stops. Basically you record a macro to search for the `%` and then delete it then move to the next line. Execute this macro a large number of times. When a `%` cannot be found the macro will stop.

```
qq0f%xjq999@q
```

The macro is my preferred method in this case as I do not need to do any crazy patterns or go looking for the end of the block.

If you allowed the use of visual mode I would suggest `vi]k:norm ^x`

For more information see:

```
:h range
:h :,
:h /\@!
:h q
:h @q
:h i]
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with `:,/]/s/%//`. Since I always know that line with `]` will not have a `%`. And thanks for the references.

Answer (score 2):

You first example is basically saying... from my current position until the next % issues the command s/%//...

What you may want to do is something like

```
:,$ s/%//
```

which says, for each line from my current position till the end of the file ($), issue the command s/%//

If you didn't want to do it till the end of the file then you could

```
:set number
```

Which will show you line numbers, then do something like

```
:2,8 s/%//
```

which just issues the command for all lines from 2-8

Comment: As said, _I do **not** want to count line numbers_.

Comment: You don't need to count anything... look at the starting line and look at the ending line... no counting involved.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `:,/%/` in a way that should use `:g/%/`. You could use your command as such: `:g/%/s/%//` or `:g/%/norm f%x`

See `:help :g` for more information on the "global" command. This basically executes a command-mode command on lines matching the pattern. Your version, `:,/%/` operates from the current line until the match of "%". This removes the first two because the current line has one and you're searching to the line that has one (the next line). You can read more about this in `:help :range`. A better way to use this option would be to use a search item that's only on the last line. For example, `:,/]/s/%//` or `:,/]/norm f%x`.